# Why does Linux have both a shadow file and passwd file?

Tags: linux, security, unix

I understand the difference between [shadow](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) and [passwd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/), but my question is why do they have both? It seems like an unnecessary complication. Why not just store the encrypted password in the passwd file? Is it somehow more secure separating them? I noticed passwd is accessible to anyone but shadow only to superusers.

Comment: While this question is a duplicate of the question pointed out by JakeGould, its original answer is incomplete because protecting the hash is not the only security concern, see below.

Answer (score 8):

The main purpose is to secure the user password hashes. The `/etc/passwd` file contains sundry user info that must be world-readable. The `/etc/shadow` file can only be read by `root`. This simple division of access rights prevents casual users and “script kiddies” from ever seeing a list of user password hashes and possibly hacking those hashes. Remember, hashes are not encrypted in any way and thus are weaker.

At one point the `shadow` file did not exist and user hashes were stored in the `passed` file [as explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#History):

> In 1987 the author of the original *Shadow Password Suite*, Julie
>   Haugh, experienced a computer break-in and wrote the initial release
>   of the Shadow Suite containing the `login`, `passwd` and `su`
>   commands. The original release, written for the SCO Xenix operating
>   system, quickly got ported to other platforms. The *Shadow Suite* was
>   ported to Linux in 1992 one year after the original announcement of
>   the Linux project, and was included in many early distributions, and
>   continues to be included in many current Linux distributions.

I remember this because the public Unix system I was on in the early 1990s announced the switch to a new setup where `/etc/shadow` would be used and there was some discussions as to whether that was a good idea or not.

More history on Julie Haugh and the creation of the *Shadow Password Suite* [can be found here](https://ef.gy/tsf-1-shadow):

> In 1987 I was the victim of a computer hacker and suddenly found the
>   need to learn everything possible about computer security. I started
>   by learning the common tricks hackers used to break into systems and
>   ended up writing the *Shadow Password Suite*. It is now the defacto
>   standard enhanced security subsystem for free UNIX systems and is
>   probably in use on over 100,000 systems world-wide. I even wrote and
>   presented a paper at a USENIX conference on it. If you are interested
>   in using the *Shadow Password Suite* on your own system, you can get a
>   copy here. I have written and presented papers or discussions at a
>   couple of conferences and look forward to possibly meeting some of you
>   at a security conference some time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of security. The `/etc/passwd` file is used by a variety of tools, and it must thus be publicly accessible. For instance `ls` matches a userid with a user name to display information about file ownerships in human-readable way.

Instead, `/etc/shadow` is only readable by root. Though unlikely that the password can be recovered from the hash stored in the file, it is still advisable to protect it from prying eyes; also, other fields are sensitive and thus deemed in need of extra protection: consider in fact that the file also stores:

> Last Password Change: This field denotes the number of days, since UNIX time (1-Jan-1970), the last password change happened.
>
> Minimum days between password changes: This field denotes the minimum number of days after which a user can change his password.
>
> Password validity: This field denoted the maximum number of days for which password is valid. After that, the password will expire and the user will have to change the password.
>
> Warning threshold: This field denotes the number of days before which the user will receive a warning notification about the password expiry.
>
> Account inactive: This field denotes the number of days after which the account will be disabled, when the password is expired.
>
> Time since account is disabled: This field denotes the number of days, from UNIX time, since which the account is disabled.

All of this information would be valuable to an attacker if it were accessible to them.

Comment: So basically having `shadow` only readable by root it's another layer of security on top of the fact that the password is encrypted?

Comment: @Celeritas Yes indeed. But the password is not encrypted: it is hashed. Should I expand on this?

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` file indeed still has a "password" field, a leftover from the early days but it's still usable – e.g. Linux has `pwconv` and `pwunconv` commands to merge/split the two files. (Though this would lose *extra* information that is also kept in the `shadow` file, such as account expiry times.)

I'm not entirely sure of the timeline; however, AFAIK, originally the `shadow` file was created because passwords weren't hashed at all – so the plaintext passwords had to be protected from being read by mere mortals. ([Export restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto_Wars) at the time meant many Unix systems did not have the [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) functions installed.) Password hashing only became widespread much later.

(Passwords are *hashed*, not encrypted; since there is no direct way to "un-hash" something, the system verifies a password by hashing it exactly the same way, and comparing both hashes.)

But even with hashed passwords, the extra layer of protection remains important. Not all hash functions are strong enough to protect a short password – for example, the same original DES-based "crypt()" hash function was strong at the time, but is considered utterly weak these days. (Some systems still use it!)

Linux crypt() now supports a wider variety of hash functions, such as `$1$` based on SHA-1 or `$5$` based on SHA-256, but the added protections (salt, multiple [rounds](https://github.com/atheme/charybdis/blob/master/libratbox/src/crypt.c#L1533-L1633)) still aren't as good as the later developments of PBKDF2 or bcrypt, and many short passwords' hashes can still be cracked in a short amount of time.

Similarly, Windows to this day uses a *very* weak hash function (just one round of MD4, no salt or any other security features). It cannot be easily upgraded, as Windows' older network authentication protocols rely on it, so the database needs to be strongly protected even from administrators (to prevent malware from obtaining it).

Answer (score 1):

There is very simple explanation for this. `passwd` file have many valuable information in it where `shadow` file contains **`encrypted`** password.

`**passwd**` file contains fallowing information

1. User Name
2. Password (x character)
3. UserID (UID)
4. GroupID(GID)
5. UserID Info
6. Home Directory
7. User Shell
   Where all attribute in **`shadow`** file contains information regarding user password, `**shadow**` file cntains fallowing info:
8. User Name
9. Password (Encrypted)
10. Last password change
11. Minimum days for password change by user
12. Maximum days for password change by user
13. Warn (days when warning for password change starts)
14. Inactive The number of days after password expires that account is disabled
15. Expire an absolute date specifying when the login may no longer be used

another difference is `passwd` file is readable by all user where in case of `shadow` only root can.

Comment: Passwords in `/etc/shadow` are hashed, not encrypted.